# Progressive Web App icon on iOS and iPadOS loses transparency

Tags: ios, icons, progressive-web-apps, ipados

I am experimenting with creating a Progressive Web Application. I've created a manifest and icons as described in https://web.dev/learn/pwa/web-app-manifest. I can install it on iOS and iPadOS as expected using *Send to*, *Add to Home Screen*.

My test icon is mostly transparent:

[image: Screenshot of icon in Paint.NET]

However, when rendered on the home screen or in the dock, my icon loses its transparency instead showing with a black background:

[image: Screenshot of icon on iPadOS home screen]

Curiously, if I click on the icon to launch the app, then swipe up to return to the home screen, the icon briefly shows correctly with transparency during the *return to home screen* animation. However, shortly afterwards it changes to show a black background again.

Here is the PNG file I'm using for my icon:

[image: Icon (PNG)]

This is `512-maskable.png`. The page I am installing from specifies:

```html
  <link rel="manifest" href="/open/pwa/app.webmanifest">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/open/pwa/icons/512-maskable.png">
```

My manifest file is:

```xml
{
    "name": "PWA Test",
    "start_url": "/open/pwa",
    "display": "standalone",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/open/pwa/icons/512.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "512x512"
        }, {
            "src": "/open/pwa/icons/1024.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "1024x1024"
        }, {
            "src": "/open/pwa/icons/192.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "192x192"
        }, {
            "src": "/open/pwa/icons/384.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "384x384"
        }, {
            "src": "/open/pwa/icons/512-maskable.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've posted a video showing the transparency disappearing after animation here: https://youtube.com/shorts/hgDhh-0Mw8I

Is it possible to keep the icon transparent on iOS and iPadOS?

Comment: Icons cannot have transparency on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, @Paulw11. Your answer, that iOS icons can’t be transparent, seems rather obvious now that I look at other icons there.